# Cookies being dropped during redirect ie11 Windows 8.1

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies

We are seeing an issue when a user tries to purchase a product in ie11 where the shopping cart id cookie gets dropped during the redirect to sercure.mydomain.com but none of our other cookies do!?! This only happens in ie11 on windows 8.1, windows 7 using ie11 and other browsers on windows 8.1 do not show this issue.

We have also updated our .net framework for this machine:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41922

And still getting nothing. Any help would be much appreciated.